# Free Linux distro for Hewlett-Packard HP xw4400 Workstation

Tags: linux, distributions

I have a system Hewlett-Packard HP xw4400 Workstation which have this characteristics:

[HP specs](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02785340)

- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU 6600 @ 2.40GHz
- RAM 2.00 GB
- 224 GB of memory storage

It works with Microsoft Windows XP Professional SP3 OS, nevertheless system performance is too bad, I mean is too slow at startup and opening installed applications like Windows Movie Maker.
I would like to install one of the latest (2018) free Linux distro for normal users (not advanced users), which allows me have a better performance. Also it would be great if that distro would have a good appearance (ex: desktop, video edition, etc.).

I know some distros like Ubuntu, Debian, but I don't know what is the best for my purpose. What distro do you recommend to me according to my system requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When one decides to choice a distro, there are many aspects (in order of importance) to take into account:

**First**, your knowledge of the Linux environment: if you are a beginner, you should opt for a distro with a big and active e.g. forum, wiki, guide that can help you and ease your life.
**Second**, the softwares you will use: different distros are focused on different uses e.g. there are distro focused on multimedia others focused on development; fortunately distros are not closed-box, that is they do not (much) preclude the use you can do with it.
**Third**, your hardware: fortunately Linux is really ductile (maybe the most one in the wild) since it's employed from mobile devices to super-computer; (this point it is a little bit difficult) Linux *slowness* depends mainly on desktop environment you use; anyway, again thanks to Linux modularity and ductility, desktop environment is distro-agnostic, that is (often) you can choose which desktop environment use.

> As you can imagine there isn't a right/best choice in absolute and there are other aspect one can take into account e.g. *security*; anyhow I think it is a widespread list of the most importat things.

---

In my opinion, ***Linux Mint XFCE 64bit*** will fit your hardware and needs.

> my honest and true suggestion is to try as distros as you want: the beauty around Linux environment is freedom and this led to a wide choice; so don't be bother, try as much distros you can

Comment: I have read that Linux Mint with Cinnamon desktop version recommends 2GB of RAM, do you think that it's a better option than XFCE? I don't know maybe It can brings more slowness ...

Comment: Cinnamon it's heavier than XFCE. This is the reason why I suggested you the latter edition

Answer (score 0):

Any decent modern distro will work.  Only advice would be up upgrade the RAM, since it is so cheap now.

Had that exact machine, upgraded RAM to 8gb quite a few years ago, was running strong and I had no issues with Mint and MATE desktop until the CPU fan died over a weekend and cooked everything else.  Wish I could re-purpose that nice heavy metal case, etc.

I have a laptop with a similar spec CPU and 2gb RAM, handles Mint w/ MATE just fine.  I've never bothered with Cinnamon or any of the eye candy features - eye candy doesn't get work done.